# Using WooCommerce. How to prompt for address before cart/checkout, based on the address (i.e. zipcode), show specific products available?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I am building out an ecommerce website using WordPress and WooCommerce. I'm able to set up my products and corresponding fees/taxes based on the address entered, but it's during checkout. I  will have two locations which could have different inventory, so looking to have the address/zipcode check well before the cart/checkout so that specific products would be shown based on the address/zipcode.

I've searched everything and anything--all I can find is based on geolocation, but the shipping (or delivery) address is what I need to know ahead of time because someone can order from a different location but for delivery within the delivery area serviced.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for something similar, but I want to force the customer to put their zip code in before checkout so I can valid their cart for delivery.

I found this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-check-pincode-zipcode-for-shipping/

I haven't tested it, but it looks like something that could work for what you are doing. It can check stock of product based on a zip code at any given location.